# Changing a index of pandas.dataframe or pandas.series object by iterating over it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

i am trying to change a index of my pandas.series object.

My approach:

```
for i, val in freq_values.iteritems():
    if i == ' ':
        freq_values[i] = 'Empty String'
```

I tried also with iloc function to select the index i wanna change, but that didnt work out.

Is it even possible or do I have to append it to a new list?

Greetings

Comment: you might try a list comprehension, i.e. `my_series.index = ['Empty String' if i == ' ' else i for i,val in freq_values.iteritems()]`, but it's a bit hard to answer your question without more details.

Comment: Yeah but i just fail finding a function to change the index 'i'. Iterating and checking works.